# Changes made in home page not displaying

Tags: templating

I am new on Craft CMS and it's the first CMS I am trying. Hey guys, I apologies is this question was asked before. I went through lot of articles and I didn't get anything helpful yet. I added  in home.html, made changes to var.scss and home.scss so that the background color of the  can be gray.

When I open the project in the browser the  is not displaying but it's visible during inspection.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14397/craft-loading-scss-references-rather-than-css)?

SCSS needs to be compiled and the page is loaded with the compiled CSS files, the SCSS references are used only for easier debugging and development. Seeing a change during inspection, does not necessarily mean that the CSS file changed, maybe there was a compilation error or something.

Comment: I downloaded sass so I can compile. I tried to compile vars.scss, home.scss and career.scss files but still, the changes are not visible. I opened cmd and ran cd dir to the directory of sass. Then ran sass --version to test it and succeeded. Than I ran sass musa/project/vars.scss and seemed to have worked just fine. I did that to all the files needed compilation. Did I follow the correct steps to compile? If not, may you please advise me on the proper way to compile?

Comment: Ok, I have vars.scss in the main templates folder (craft/templates), in the _layouts folder I have home folder (craft/templates/_layouts/home/home.scss) and careers folder (craft/templates/_layouts/careers/careers.scss). The home.scss and careers.scss imports vars.scss. in the assets folder there is a bundle.css file (assets/bundle.css) that maps (assets/bundle.css.map) the the vars.scss. I tried to run sass --watch vars.scss:bundle.css and the entire styling of bundle.css was changed completely and the rest was broken. How do I compile without braking the rest of the styling?